# How do I map this relationship? A customer had many previous address but only 1 current address (Bidirectional relationship)

Tags: hibernate, jpa

A customer had many address but only one current address.

Therefore in my Oracle I will have the following tables:

```
CUSTOMER
CUSTOMER_ID
NAME
CURRENT_ADDRESS

ADDRESS
ADDRESS_ID
CUSTOMER_ID
ADDRESS_DETAILS
```

I can't seems to mapped out my hibernate relationship to be able to set its current address and have a list to find all its previous address

Do I need a weak relationship to denotes it current address?

ie

```
CURRENT_ADDRESS
CUSTOMER_ID
ADDRESS_ID
```

I'm sure this is a common issue that has been solved before.

Answer (score 0):

1. remove the current_address pointer in the **customer** table.

   2. add an indicator in the **address** table : IS_CURRENT.
   3. create a view that will select only the IS_CURRENT = TRUE addresses.
   4. connect this view to the **customer**'s entity using @OneToOne annotation.

you can find other solutions including mine in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965626/database-design-consideration-on-foreign-key-both-way-between-two-tables/17968123#comment26270124_17968123)

hope it helped you :)

Comment: for some reason I can't use view.